# mongoDB php update not working

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to update each document in a mongoDB collection with a new field. This works fine when selecting a specific document by its mongoID and then inserting a specific field but when I try to do it in a loop it somehow stops working. See code below. Anyone know why this is failing?

```
$m = new MongoClient();
$db = $m->selectDB('SocialMedia');
$collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'testcoord');
$myC = $collection->find();
foreach($myC as $tweet){
$testCoord = array($tweet['coordinates']['coordinates'][0],$tweet['coordinates']['coordinates'][1]);
    foreach ($areaArray as $area) {
        if (pointInPolygon($area,$testCoord)){
            $collection->update(array('_id'=>$tweet['_id']),array('$set' => array('city_area' => $area['areaName'])));
        }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example code is not full because there is no definitions of $areaArray and pointInPolygon() so it is harder to see what your goal is.

However, note that you updating same document multiple times in a foreach cycle, so your *city_area* field is re-writing each time (this is how [$set](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator works).

```
    // this is how your updates go
    $collection->update(['_id' => 'tweet_1'], ['$set' => ['city_area' => 'value1']);
    $collection->update(['_id' => 'tweet_1'], ['$set' => ['city_area' => 'value2']);
    $collection->update(['_id' => 'tweet_1'], ['$set' => ['city_area' => 'value3']);
    // now your document with id = 'tweet_1' contains 'city_area' = 'value3'
    // 'value1' and 'value2' are rewrited
```

If you want to store multiple values in one field, use [$addToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) operator instead.
Otherwise, fix your code according your goal.

For example, this code works perfectly:

```
    $mongoClient = new MongoClient();
    $db = $mongoClient->selectDB('Test');
    $collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'test_collection');

    // inserting 5 documents with values from 1 to 5
    foreach (range(1, 5) as $value) {
        $collection->insert(
            ['value' => $value]
        );
    }

    // find and update each document with new value
    $cursor = $collection->find();
    foreach ($cursor as $doc) {
        $newValue = 2; // insert here your code, calculating new value for each document
        $collection->update(
            ['_id'=>$doc['_id']], 
            ['$set' => ['value' => newValue]]
        );
    }
    // now we have 5 documents with field 'value' equals 2 each
```